# Laravel get all data form two Models and rank them by timestamp

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I'm making this Laravel project, in which the dashboard consists of a 'timeline' showing all messages and notifications orderd by the time they occured ('created_at').

So there are messages (id, text, author, timestamps) and notifications(id, action, actegory, object) each having different fields.

```
 $messages=Message::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();
 $notifications=Notification::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();
```

But I'm looking for a way to order them **together** by created_at. Something like:

```
array(
message1
notification1
notifcation2
message2
message3
)
```

Furthermore, I'm looking to a way to then check for each of these elements whether it's a notification or a message.

Would anyone know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
class MessageNotificationComposite implements IteratorAggregate
{
    private $_elements;

    function __construct(array $elements)
    {
        usort(
            $elements,
            function ($a, $b) {
                if ($a->created_at > $b->created_at) {
                    return 1;
                } elseif ($a->created_at < $b->created_at) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        );
        $this->_elements = $elements;
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->_elements);
    }
}

$messages = Message::all();
$notifications = Notification::all();

$mnArray = new MessageNotificationComposite(array_merge($messages, $notifications));

foreach($mnArray as $item) {
    echo get_class($item);
}
```

Comment: Looks great,would you put this class in a controller or as a library?

Comment: Composite class - as a library, calls - wherever you need it.

Comment: Ok, but I'm getting the error that $messages and $notifications are no arrays

Comment: I have a typo there - `$notification` and `$notifications`

Comment: I got the error after fixing that. Maybe it's because of the JSON format?

Comment: Can you show me your actual code? Simple `::all()` doesn't return JSON format, as far as i remember...

Comment: OK, 
` $messages = Message::all();
$notifications = Notification::all();
$mnArray = new MessageNotificationComposite(array_merge($notifications,$messages));

return $mnArray;
 `

Comment: Try to `var_dump` `$messages` and `$notifications`, perhaps, one of them is empty?

Comment: I think it is no array but some other type like JSON, because when I try the function with only $messages, I get this error: 'Argument 1 passed to MessageNotificationComposite::__construct() must be of the type array, object given'

Comment: It's strange, default behavior for `::all()` method is to return an array of `Eloquent` objects.